# Has an NHL or NBA champion ever won all playoffs series with the same record?

Tags: basketball, nba, ice-hockey, nhl, postseason

After losing game 3 of the 2019-20 NBA finals, the Los Angeles Lakers lead the Miami Heat 2-1 in the series. The Lakers got to the finals after beating the Portland Blazers, the Houston Rockets, and the Denver Nuggets in the first three rounds of the playoffs with a score of 4-1 in each of those series. The Lakers are now 2 wins away from winning the championship and winning all series 4-1.
(Note that the Lakers ended up winning the series 4-2 and didn't achieve this feat).

Since the NHL and the NBA playoffs have been played a best of 7 series on all rounds, has there ever been a team winning all rounds with the exact same score?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NHL has been hosting best of 7 playoff rounds since the [1986-87](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_Cup_playoffs#Divisional_playoffs) season. Looking at [Hockey Reference](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/) there has been no Stanley Cup champion winning all rounds with the same score.

The NBA has been hosting best of 7 playoff rounds 2002-03 season where the [San Antonio Spurs](https://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/NBA_2003.html) on that year became the first and only NBA team to to this date
winning all series with the same record.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.  One example is the [2002-03 San Antonio Spurs](https://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/NBA_2003.html), who won all four series they played 4 games to 2.